# Django - how to get file input without using django form and attach the file to email

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I am trying to get file input from a html form without using django form and then attach that file to email.

My HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'foo' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file1"/>
</form>
```

My views.py:

```
def foo(request):
  if not request.FILES['file1']:
     return render(request, 'index.html', {})
  email_msg = EmailMessage(subject="email subject", body="email body",
            from_email="email@adress", to=["email@adress"])
  email_msg.attach_file(request.FILES['file1'])
  email_msg.send()

  return render(request, 'needs-confirmation.html', context
```

I have two questions. First, in the function foo, I put the if statement to first check if the user has put the file and that file1 exists. This works fine when a file is uploaded as file1 but, this gives an error when file1 does not have any file input. How can I check if file1 exists or not? Second question is when I am trying to attach file to email_msg, attach_file function does not work, giving this error:

```
'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

How can I get file from html form and attach the file to an email?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should look something like this:

```
def foo(request):
#need to check that form was submitted
if request.method == "POST":
    #this checks that a file exists
    if len(request.FILES) != 0:
        file1 = request.FILES['file1']
        file1str = file1.read()
        file_type = str(request.FILES['file1'].content_type)
        email_msg = EmailMessage(subject="email subject", body="email body",
        from_email="...", to=["..."])
        #need to try to attach the file, using the attach method
        try:
            email_msg.attach('file1', file1str, file_type)
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
        email_msg.send()
return render(request, '/needs-confirmation.html', {})
```

You will need to fill in the emails again.
You've left out a lot of key steps, and your HTML needs a submit button and crsf_token. This works for text files, you may need to do some more processing for other file types.

Hope this helps.